# Why are Moonshine/Capistrano having SFTP trouble during deploy:setup?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano

I'm having trouble setting up a new server using Moonshine and Capistrano. It seems to get started pretty well, installs a bunch of Ubuntu packages, compiles REE, installs some gems, but then it fails to upload a file via SFTP with this output:

```
  * executing `moonshine:setup_directories'
  * executing "mkdir /tmp/moonshine"
    servers: ["myserver.tld"]
    [myserver.tld] executing command
    command finished
    servers: ["myserver.tld"]
 ** sftp upload /Users/arussell/Sites/mysite/config/moonshine/production.yml -> /tmp/moonshine/production.yml
/Users/arussell/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.03/gems/capistrano-2.5.19/lib/capistrano/transfer.rb:196:in `normalize': undefined method `pos' for #<Pathname:0x10f3a6988> (NoMethodError)
    from /Users/arussell/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.03/gems/capistrano-2.5.19/lib/capistrano/transfer.rb:104:in `prepare_transfers'
```

Googling that error isn't really turning much up, all I can figure out is that capistrano/transfer.rb is expecting something other than a PathName object on line 196, but I'm not sure what it's expecting, nor am I sure why it's being fed a PathName object.

---

**Edit:** Here is my deploy.rb:

```
set :stages, %w(staging production dev)
set :default_stage, "staging"
require 'capistrano/ext/multistage' rescue "YOU NEED TO INSTALL THE capistrano-ext GEM"
require 'fileutils'

if ENV['branch']
  set :branch, ENV['branch']
end

set :deploy_via, :remote_cache

before "deploy:restart", "deploy:delete_cache"

namespace(:deploy) do
  desc "delete cache"
  task :delete_cache do
    run "rm -rf /usr/local/shared/cache/"
  end
  task :null, :roles => :app do
    run "date"
  end
end
require './config/boot'
```

... and my deploy/production.rb:

```
server "myserver.tld", :app, :web, :db, :primary => true

set :rails_env, 'production'
```

---

**Edit 2:** I tried using SCP instead of SFTP, but that didn't go any better. I added this to my deploy/production.rb:

```
upload "local", "remote", :via => :scp
download "remote", "local", :via => :scp
```

and got this error instead while trying to deploy:

```
upload via scp failed on myserver.tld: SCP did not finish successfully () (SCP did not finish successfully ())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that this was due to Moonshine not being able to handle the presence of deploy-stage-specific files (eg `config/moonshine/production.yml`) during `cap production deploy:setup`.

Here's how I got around it:

- Remove `config/moonshine/production.yml` (replace `production` with whatever your deploy stage is called)
- Run `cap production deploy:setup`
- Put `config/moonshine/production.yml` back
- Then run `cap production deploy`

Answer (score 0):

I can't figure that error out either.  It appears the version of Capistrano your using is fairly outdated by a year plus.  I would update the version your using to a more recent release, and try again.

If that still doesn't resolve your problem it would help if you provided sanitized copy of your deploy.rb configuration.

Comment: Good catch, though updating Capistrano to 2.9.0 didn't help: I still see the same error. I've edited the question to add sanitised versions of config/deploy.rb and config/deploy/production.rb.